# How to save state of menu on when navigating site?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have an array of `div` elements that are dynamically loaded, here the "posts" divs populate the menu container with a scroll event:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <div class="posts"></div>
        <div class="posts"></div>
        <div class="posts"></div>
        <div class="posts"></div>
        <div class="posts"></div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

When someone clicks on one of the posts they get taken to that page, I want to save the state of this menu and load it on the page I am navigating to.

I'm using the jQuery library and Wordpress.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can I post Javascript *without* JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

```
localStorage.state = $('#menu').html();
```

to save it, and

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = localStorage.state;
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

to load it.  To add it to an element,

```
document.getElementById('IDOfYourElement').innerHTML = localStorage.state;
```

will work.

Comment: Ohho, that looks dead easy, I was expecting something far more complicated, let me give it a go and I'll report back.

Comment: @UzumakiDev I edited my answer so the div will be *added* to the page rather than having an element contain it.

Comment: Hey, could you add that previous answer you had as well? I think that's the one I need.

Comment: @UzumakiDev Sure, and since you appreciate my answer you can also **upvote.**

Comment: @UzumakiDev Any time (I love REP) :)